# Как с помощью регулярного выражения обернуть текстовую ссылку в тег A?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, javascript

Добрый день, есть php-код, который оборачивает текстовую ссылку в тег `a`.
На входе `site.ru`, а на выходе `<a href="site.ru">site.ru</a>`.

```
$text = preg_replace("#(https?|ftp)://\S+[^\s.,> )\];'\"!?]#", '<a href="\\0">\\0</a>', $text)
```

Есть 1 проблема: при редактировании, к примеру, поста, содержащего ссылку, мне выводит подобную штуку:

[image]

Как переписать указанный php-код на JavaScript? Уже всё перепробовал, но так и не получается получить нужный результат.

Comment: @in1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

php => js

```
var re = /(https?|ftp):\/\/\S+[^\s.,> )\];'\"!?]/; 
var str = 'https://site.ru';
var subst = '<a href="$&">$&</a>'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score -1):

На JS парсить... Не кошерно как-то...
Но можно так:

> jsfiddle.net/00ju2qfq/3/

```js
if ( ! String.prototype.parseUrl ) {
/**
 * Considers the string object as URL and returns it's parts separately
 *
 * @param boolean str - Вернуть строку
 * @return Object
 * @access public
 */
String.prototype.parseUrl = function(str){
    str = str || false;
    var matches = this.match(arguments.callee.re);

    if (!matches){
        return null;
    }
    
    var result = {
        'scheme': matches[1] || '',
        'subscheme': matches[2] || '',
        'user': matches[3] || '',
        'pass': matches[4] || '',
        'host': matches[5],
        'port': matches[6] || '',
        'path': matches[7] || '',
        'query': matches[8] || '',
        'fragment': matches[9] || ''
    };
    
    var string = (((tmp = result.scheme) !== '') ? tmp + '://' : '') + result.subscheme + result.user + result.pass + result.host + result.port + result.path + result.query + (((tmp = result.fragment) !== '') ? '#' + tmp : '');
    
    return str ? string : result;
};

String.prototype.parseUrl.re = /^(?:([a-z]+):(?:([a-z]*):)?\/\/)?(?:([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?@)?((?:[a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|localhost|(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(?::(\d+))?(?:([^:\?\#]+))?(?:\?([^\#]+))?(?:\#([^\s]+))?$/i;

}



var uri = 'http://my-site.com/my-page.php#my-anchor';
var parse = uri.parseUrl(true);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<a href="' + parse + '">' + parse + '</a>';
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: Вот только проблема возникает, если ссылка выглядит так: http://i.imgur.com/QYhLN0r.png

В любой случае, ставлю $0 - в ссылку он не преобразуется...

Comment: @in1, вот решение - https://jsfiddle.net/00ju2qfq/3/

Comment: Да, вот только теперь главный, вопрос -_-, как этот скрипт реализовать вот примерно так: http://i.imgur.com/6xau7XQ.png, ибо мой парсер текста совсем другой, а всунуть ваш скрипт в свой парсер, у меня не получается, уж извините, за такие примитивные косяки, ибо я только недавно начал изучать js, и в 1 раз встречаюсь с такой проблемой.

Comment: @in1, в случае провала обнаружения ссылки, скрипт вернёт `null`.  Смекаешь?  
Ежели не хочешь что-то у себя менять, то вот регулярка для проверки:  
`console.info(/^(?:([a-z]+):(?:([a-z]*):)?\/\/)?(?:([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?@)?((?:[a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|localhost|(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(?::(\d+))?(?:([^:\?\#]+))?(?:\?([^\#]+))?(?:\#([^\s]+))?$/i.test('http://my-site.com/my-page.php#my-anchor'));`

Comment: Вот, поставил парсер - while(/^(?:([a-z]+):(?:([a-z]*):)?\/\/)?(?:([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?@)?((?:[a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|localhost|(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(?::(\d+))?(?:([^:\?\#]+))?(?:\?([^\#]+))?(?:\#([^\s]+))?$/i.test(b)) b = b.replace(/^(?:([a-z]+):(?:([a-z]*):)?\/\/)?(?:([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?@)?((?:[a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|localhost|(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(?::(\d+))?(?:([^:\?\#]+))?(?:\?([^\#]+))?(?:\#([^\s]+))?$/g, "<a>$1</a>"); - результат: http://i.imgur.com/d4o4Ma4.png

Comment: @in1, я не дал тебе рыбу, я дал тебе удочку.  
Это только регулярное выражение, которое тебе нужно. Из него уже нужно собрать что тебе надо.  
Хотя могу и рыбу дать:  
`var replace = 'http://my-site.com/my-page.php#my-anchor - это мой сайт, а сайт http://my-emeny.fuu/ - дрянь'.replace(/((?:([a-z]+):(?:([a-z]*):)?\/\/)?(?:([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?@)?((?:[a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|localhost|(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(?::(\d+))?(?:([^:\?\#\s]+))?(?:\?([^\#]+))?(?:\#([^\s]+))?)/ig, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');`